# Variable php empty suggestion

Tags: php, mysql

```
// gets the user IP Address
$user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (empty($user_ip)) {
    // ...
} else {
    $id3 = $row['id'];
    $titlesong = $row['title'];
    $check_ip = mysqli_query($conn, "select userip from pageview where page='$titlesong' and userip='$user_ip'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($check_ip)>=1) {
        // ...
    } else {
        $insertview = mysqli_query($conn,"insert into pageview values('$id3','$titlesong','$user_ip','$year','$month','$day')");
    }

    // some data...
}
```

I have made this code to get the pageviews inserted in database, but i get some blank ips, I have used `if (empty($user_ip))` to not insert that viewer in database, but it did not work, can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can also include `$user_ip == ''`:

```
if( (empty($user_ip)) || ($user_ip == '') )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively look for a better IP format checker, but a minimal one for IPv4 could be:

if( strlen($user_ip) < 7 )

because of counting at least 4 numbers one digit each, and 3 dots.

Answer (score 0):

> Use PHP's `FILTER_VALIDATE_IP`

Read up on W3Schools [FILTER_VALIDATE_IP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_ip.asp)

Additional parameters can be found on PHP Docs [FILTER_VALIDATE_IP](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)